# Yaaleh VeYavo during/after early Maariv on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: tefilla

When you daven Maariv early (right after plag hamincha) on Rosh Chodesh, it seems you shouldn't say Yaaleh VeYavo.

1. Why is this, since it's still day time and hence still Rosh Chodesh?
2. If you then eat a meal (after you davened Maariv, but while it's still daylight), would you need to say Yaaleh VeYavo in bentching?

Comment: Why do you ask this and not on amida of motzei Shabbos on Shabbos afternoon

Comment: @AKA Because that's uncommon and discouraged.

Comment: True, but it's an explicit Gemara (Brachos 27) that that is the correct approach if you are doing it. Is yaaleh veyavo a Gemara (might be tbh, don't think so)?